# Revolution Slider Layers Disappear On Mobile

Tags: jquery, wordpress, mobile, revolution-slider

I am using Revolution Slider on a WordPress website and on the main interface, the slide looks great on a desktop. On a mobile phone however, some elements do not appear.

On the main Rev Slider interface I changed the configuration to mobile so I can investigate and the elements were actually but faded and transparent. How do I fix this? Check screenshot attached[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e80t0.jpg)

Comment: Try to check the "Layer Visibility" as explained here https://www.sliderrevolution.com/documentation/responsive-settings/#device-visibility

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tut - you may have to manually adjust elements in the editing platform while previewing each device view one by one:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hP4oV8SWgKY

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32720375)

Answer (score 0):

There is a visibility option when you click on elements in slider revolution. That is helpful when you want to exclude some elements appearing on mobile version or tablet. Check it out.